# How to draw simple graphs, paths, arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, xy-pic, draw

I´m trying to learn how to draw with LaTeX, but I have found too much info about that:

```
 1. XY-Pic
 2. pgfplot 
 3. tikz
 4. LaTeXDraw
 5. PSTricks
```

So I need to focus in one package/tool each time to dominate that and after that other tool and other and other... To try to understand this kind of packages/tools I would like to draw simple graphs/diagrams like that ones:
[image: Money and time]

[image: Interest, time and money]

[image: Present and future value of money/rent]

I don´t know how to start, so anyone can recommend me any package or tool to draw that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's rare to hear that "too much information" is the problem. To learn Ti*k*Z (which, I think, hast the most novice-friendly syntax) you can follow the tutorials [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PGF/TikZ), and [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/27/tikz-series-pt1.html) for a start. Then you can use the step-by-step guides from the [PGF manual](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). Then, if you are stuck on a specific problem, you can ask us how to solve it.

Comment: It's helpfull when the OP brings some picture or hand drawing photo to explain what they need, but its necessary to add the attempt code to scape from the "do it for me" situation to "helpme to achieve this", who urges to help in a good way; I think that tilkz is the most popular, just look at the more than 20K queries, if the **PGF manual** seems very long you could use [visual tikz](http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf) a **code-result manual**, you will see that it is possible to draw almost anything in 2D, the code optimization is already a matter of experience...

Comment: Thanxs to you. Im looking thats url´s you sent me and Im doing all of those "exercises" to try to understand all the commands. Thanxs!

Answer (score 4):

There are better solutions out there, but it works:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 45,every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
            \draw (0,0) -- (5.5,0);
            \draw (-.15,0) circle(.05) node[below=8] {$t_0$};
            \draw (5.65,0) circle(.05) node[below=8] {$t_T$};
                \node[above=8] at (5.65,0) {$n\Delta t$};
        \foreach \x in {1,2.5,4}
        {
            \draw (\x,.2) -- (\x,-.2);
        }
            \node[below=3] at (1,-.2) {$t_s$};
            \node[above=3] at (1,.2) {$s\Delta t$};
                \node[above=3] at (4,.2) {$(i+1)\Delta t$};
            \draw[->] (2.5,-.3) --+ (0,-.5) node[midway,right] {\tiny $C_i$};
            \draw[->] (4,-.3) --+ (0,-.5) node[midway,right] {\tiny $C_{i+1}$};
        \draw[shorten <=.1cm,shorten >=.1cm,->] (2.5,0) to[bend right=40] (1,0);
        \draw[shorten <=.1cm,shorten >=.1cm,->] (4,0) to[bend right=40] (1,0);
            \node[fill=white,above=3] at (2.5,.2) {$i\Delta t$};
        \begin{scope}[>=latex,shift={(0,-2.5)}]
            \draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0);
            \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (5,-3);
                \draw (0,1) -- (0,-4);
            \foreach \x in {1,2,...,4}
            {
                \draw[dashed] (\x,1) -- (\x,-4);
            }
            \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
            {
                \draw[thick] (\x,0) -- (\x+1,.5) -- (\x+1,0);
                \node[above left] at (\x+1,.5) {I};
            }
            \draw[thick] (4,0) -- (3,-.5) -- (3,-1) -- (2,-1.5) -- (2,-2) -- (1,-2.5) -- (1,-3) -- (0,-3);
                \draw[dashed] (2.5,-.5) -- (4,-.5);
            \foreach \x in {1,2}
            {
                \draw[dashed,xshift=-\x cm,yshift=-\x cm] (2.5,-.5) -- (4,-.5);
            }
                \node[xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm,below right] at (4,.5) {$F_{3}$};
                \node[xshift=-2cm,yshift=-2cm,below right] at (4,.5) {$F_{2}$};
                \node[xshift=-3cm,yshift=-3cm,below right] at (4,.5) {$F_{1}$};
            \draw[>=angle 45,<->] (4,0) to[bend left=40] (4,-3) node[midway,right=5,xshift=4.5cm,yshift=-1.5cm] {$D$};
                \node[below] at (.5,0) {\resizebox{.8cm}{!}{Pr\'{e}stamo}};
                \node[below] at (.5,-3) {\resizebox{.8cm}{!}{Dep\'{o}sito}};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-8)}]
            \draw[|-|,dashed] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[midway,above] {\footnotesize $T$};
            \draw[-|] (2.1,0) -- (2.8,0) node[midway,above] {$r$};
                \draw (2.8,0) -- (3.5,0) node[right] (a) {\ldots};
            \draw[-|] (a.east) --+ (.7,0) node[midway,above] {$r$};
            \draw[->] ($(a.east)+(.7,0)$) --+ (.7,0) node[right=2] {$t$};
                \node[below=5] at (0,-.3) {VA};
                \node[above left] at (0,0) {\tiny Hoy};
            \draw[->] (2,.2) --+ (0,.7) node[midway,right=-2] {\tiny $C_1$};
            \draw[->] (2.8,.2) --+ (0,.7) node[midway,right=-2] {\tiny $C_2$};
            \draw[->] (4.85,.2) --+ (0,.7) node[midway,right=-2] {\tiny $C_n$};
                \node[below right=-1] at (2,-.15) {\footnotesize $t_0$};
                \node[below right=-1] at (2.8,-.15) {\footnotesize $t_1$};
                \node[below right=-1] at (4.85,-.15) {\footnotesize $t_n$};
            \node[below right=-1] at (4.85,-.5) {VF};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Uauu!! Thank you very much. I was learning Tikzpackage with some exercises but this code awesome. I can watch it and learn about the orders. Thanks you again and again and \loop{100times}[and again].